# foreach loop and unexpected else in php when using html dom parser

Tags: php, html, xpath, simpledom

I have write a code to use html simple dom parser, here it is :

```
<?php $opts = array(   'http'=>array( 
   'header'=>"User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53\r\n"   ) );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    set_time_limit(0);
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $lines = file('BQ.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
       $html = file_get_html($line, false, $context);
       if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
          echo $line; 
       }
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){
            if ($element) { } 
            echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>";
       } else {
            echo "kosong" 
       }
        echo "</ul>"; 
     }
     $html->clear(); ?>
```

But it always Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)
I have tried so many way but still got no solution, the problem is only 
   else{
    echo "sorry empty"
   }

If I run the script without it, it run perfectly

Comment: Else part started after end of second for each and move your echo inside the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code. Please compare your code with below:

```
<?php $opts = array(   'http'=>array( 
   'header'=>"User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53\r\n"   ) );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    set_time_limit(0);
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $lines = file('BQ.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
       $html = file_get_html($line, false, $context);
       if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
          echo $line; 
       }
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){
            if ($element) {
                echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>";
            } else {
                echo "kosong" ;
            }
       }
        echo "</ul>"; 
     }
     $html->clear(); ?>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot echo "kosong" ;
i have fix it, but still cant echo "kosong" just echo $line in result

Answer (score 0):

> Sytax error : Else part started after end of second for each and move your echo inside the if condition

```
          <?php $foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
           $html = file_get_html($line, false, $context);
           if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){
              echo $line; 
           }
           echo "<ul>";
           foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){
                if ($element) { echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>"; } 
                else {
                echo "kosong" 
               }
           } 
            echo "</ul>"; 
         }
    ?>
```

Comment: echo $line; 
       }
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){
            if ($element) {
                echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>";
            } else {
                echo "kosong" ;
            }
       }
        echo "</ul>"; 
     }
     $html->clear(); 
  ?>

still no echo "kosong" in result

Comment: else part only echo when if statement is false . so may be always true  @FunTasticfantastic

Comment: the else will not echo because the first foreach is true,

Can that be the problem?

Comment: may be if ($element)  is always true so else part will not echo

Comment: what i mean is only "else" just for the second foreach But it seems to be a part for the whole script

Answer (score 0):

Main Problem is here

```
if ($element) { } 
        echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>";
   } else {
        echo "kosong" 
   }
    echo "</ul>"; 
 }
 $html->clear(); ?>
```

Solution is ...

```
f ($element) {
        echo "<li>".$element ->plaintext. "</li>";
   } else {
        echo "kosong" ;
   }
    echo "</ul>"; 
 }
 $html->clear();
}?>
```

It parse fine.

Comment: sorry i forgot ;
but still there is no echo "kosong" in result

Comment: echo "kosong"   is in else block. So it works when previous if fail.

Comment: i think so,, what i mean is i only want to else just for the second foreach But it seems to be a part for the whole script

Comment: foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){ //If else block }   here you put your second if else block.  Then it must be part of the second foreach loop.  Now make a thing clear that, in your code there are two foreach loop, are those nested or separated??

Comment: i want it separated

Comment: @FunTasticfantastic Then you must be write  foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){// Code for first foreach block }  foreach($html->find("h1[class='productname'],  div[class='productprice']") as $element ){ //Code for second foreach block} .In your code there is a great problem related with " { }" .  You must be careful with, where it starts and where it ends.